# Clones won't get destroyed by script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need some help making this script work.

```c#
#pragma strict

function OnMouseDown () {
Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Basically what the script does is that it destroys the objects that the player clicks on.I also got another object which has a script attached to it,which makes it spawn other objects.

The script clones the objects and makes it spawn multiple times.I attached the first script to the prefab but when I click on it,it won't be destroyed.If I click on the original prefab it works,but not on the clones created by the other script.

Does anyone have any idea why it's not working?

Edit :

Spawner script :

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] obj;
public float spawnMin = 1f;
public float spawnMax = 2f;


void Start () {
    Spawn ();
}

void Spawn() 
{
    Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))],transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your clones?

Comment: It's in C#  :

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
 
 public GameObject[] obj;
 public float spawnMin = 1f;
 public float spawnMax = 2f;
 
 
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  Spawn ();
 }
 
 void Spawn() 
 {
  Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))],transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
  Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
 }
 
}

Comment: Any chance you can edit that into your question so it's legible? :)

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does your object have a collider?

Comment: I have no errors and yes my object does have a collider (Circle collider 2D).